# Vue 3 algolia-instant-search gets reset when using a toggle button for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, algolia

So I'm using a toggle menu for mobile devices, however my attributes for the filter seem to be reset when I close it. I tried putting the ais-hierarchial-menu into a component to separate the state but to no avail. My filter values still get reset. A summary of my code:

```js
const closeFilter = ref(true);
const hierarchicalMenuOpen = ref(false);

function toggleFilter() {
  closeFilter.value = !closeFilter.value;
  hierarchicalMenuOpen.value = !hierarchicalMenuOpen.value;
  document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle("overflow-hidden");
}

return {
  toggleFilter,
  closeFilter,
  hierarchicalMenuOpen,
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

    <div v-show="!closeFilter" 
<button @click="toggleFilter" class="filter-search-btn">
      <span>
      <i :class="closeFilter ? 'fal fa-filter' : 'fal fa-times'"></i>
      {{ closeFilter ? 'Filter' : 'Close' }}
      </span>
      </button>
    </div>
<HierarchialMenu v-show="hierarchicalMenuOpen" :hierarchicalMenuOpen="hierarchicalMenuOpen" />
```

Comment: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/widgets/show-and-hide-widgets/vue/  is this what u looking for